# Asyncio put to queue.Queue

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, python-3.5, python-asyncio

A pretty simple question that I haven't been able to find an answer to:

If I want to run an asyncio event loop in its own thread, and have it send messages back to the main thread, can it do so using a `queue.Queue` instance?

If this is indeed possible and safe, is there a better way of passing messages from an asyncio loop in a non-main thread, to the main thread?

Here's a toy example, which seems to work:

```
import asyncio
from queue import Queue
import threading

queue_to_main = Queue()


async def coro1():

    for i in range(5):
        queue_to_main.put_nowait(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    queue_to_main.put_nowait("STOP")


def runloop():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(coro1())
    finally:
        loop.close()


t1 = threading.Thread(target=runloop)
t1.start()

while True:
    item = queue_to_main.get()
    if item == "STOP":
        break
    print(item)

t1.join()
```

The scenario I'm envisaging is running an aiohttp server in its own thread, but letting in communicate back to the main thread as a result of certain requests.

Comment: Do you specifically want to avoid using `asyncio.Queue`?

Comment: Not particularly - I would be happy to use it if that ends up being the best way of doing things in this sort of scenario. However, I guess there would be some complications getting an item from an `asyncio.Queue` instance in the main thread, since `asyncio.Queue` isn't threadsafe?

I guess you might have to do something like:
`item = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(my_aio_queue.get(), loop).result()`?

Comment: Related: [janus](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus)

Answer (score -2):

`asyncio.Queue` is intended for usage inside the single event loop.
The queue is not inter-loop communication primitive.

Moreover, you should not start several parallel loops, each in own thread. It is antipattern (at least for Python).

Comment: In what way is this supposed to be an answer to the question? 
I have the same problem myself, I need to establish synchronous communication between async code running in an event loop in the main thread, and sync code running in an executor (embedded thread/process) within that event loop. I have spent the past three days diving into the inner workings of asyncio and reading through the official documentation, and just like the OP I cannot seem to find any examples explaining how inter-thread/ inter-process communication between sync and async threads is best implemented..

Comment: The only solutions I have been able to find are;
1) Use an ordinary (thread safe) queue and then wrap the .put() and .get() methods in executors for running inside the async code, and just use the other end of the queue in normal sync code.
2) Schedule async coroutine execution from the sync thread with arguments (using the thread safe method), and wait for the result of the Future object returned by coroutine, after it has been successfully executed in the async thread.
3) Use sockets or pipes (Unix only) between the threads.
All of the above sort of feel like hacks to me..